# MS Excel - Separate text based on keyword

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, spreadsheet

I need to separate text based on a keyword to different columns. the original text is in one column but I want to split the intended subtext into different columns. The problem in this case is I get different characters after the intended keywork. Also, as you can see in the below image, in the text column, keywords are not ordered.

[image]

And here's the above image [spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eYeZfTMJ-oGTrE9IaY_v8fcgmsDdrjFw/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: You need some data (a header, for example) which will specify what text part to what column must be placed. At least.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood your comment, but I updated the picture and the file if you meant that.

Comment: In such form the task is simple enough. Search the header in a value. If not found, then print empty string. If found then search for a comma after found position. If not found assume it is equal to value length. Then get substring between these 2 found values.

Comment: That makes sense. Appreciate it if you wrote the function or the VBA code.

Comment: No, formula can do this, no VBA needed.

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi,,  could you share the formula / VBA code you have tried so far,, will help us to fix it !!

Comment: @RajeshS , I haven't written any formula or VBA. Was wondering if you could help in that.

Comment: @Akina appreciate it if you wrote the formula.

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi,, now check my post I've solved it ☺

Comment: you _definitely_ do not need VBA or probably Excel add-ins to do this task. Is the string you want to copy always the length of the header + 2 characters?

Comment: @AlexM Yes, it's the length of the header plus n number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Combination of VBA Function & Helper values, solves your problem:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this VBA code as **M**odule:

  ```
  Function FindWord(Source As String, Position As Integer)

   Dim arr() As String
   arr = VBA.Split(Source, " ")
   xCount = UBound(arr)
   If xCount < 1 Or (Position - 1) > xCount Or Position < 0 Then
   FindWord = ""
    Else
   FindWord = arr(Position - 1)
   End If
   End Function
  ```
- Formula in cell `R65`, & fill it across.

  ```
  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(SEARCH(R$64,$Q65),{1,12,25,37},{1,2,3,4}),"")
  ```

**Edited:**

- An alternative formula in cell `R65`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(LOOKUP(SEARCH(R$64,$Q65),SEARCH($R$64:$U$64,$Q$65)-2,{1,2,3,4}),"")
  ```

*Fill formula across.*

- Formula in cell `R70`, and also fill it across.

  `=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FindWord($Q65,R65),",",""),""`)

**N.B.** *This formula is for Excel users.*

***Edited:***

*Since OP is using Google Sheet & VBA macro doesn't supports it, so that I would like to suggest an alternative formula in cell `R70`.*

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($Q65," ",REPT(" ",LEN($Q65))), (R65-1)*LEN($Q65)+1, LEN($Q65))),",",""),"")
```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: I used the alternative formula in R65 and adjusted the cell references and got the result in your image. But when I used the formula in cell R70 (with cell adjustments), I didn't get the result and it showed me FALSE in all the applied cells. 
I updated [the same spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eYeZfTMJ-oGTrE9IaY_v8fcgmsDdrjFw/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi, glad to help you,, since you are using Google sheet so that old formula in R70 was not working,, now check the recently edited part in the post & use an alternative formula , will work properly !! Please [Edit] your post & add new TAG `Google Sheet` also.

Comment: In fact I'm using MS Excel but your latest update worked perfectly. So I guess you gotta update your latest update to say that it works for MS Excel as well.

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi,, just now I've examined the sheet,, unfortunately you did not saved the MACRO I've suggested with my post,, after I've saved in (downloaded sheet) ,, OLD formula is also working,, please don't forget to save the Wbook as Macor Enabled `.XLSX`,, ☺

Comment: @ImanGhavamabadi,, just [Check this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rqTUFScVDmSslJC-zIp4mojF0JKJP_uE) .

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should have done that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I use free Excel [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in in similar cases, with that you can use this formula:

`=RegExFind($A2,C$1&"/[a-z]+")`

[image]

*I'm not affiliated with the tool.*